# enable debug mode in PHP, Window Dos

Tags: php, windows, command-line

in windows command line.

how to enable debug in ftp commands,

second questions 
in PHP how to enable the debug mode,

below is the simple ftp script,

How to get step by step script execution trace for the FTP.

i guess there is something debug mode in php, please advise that mode,

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = 'readme.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: You want to debug what?

Comment: from connection open to connection close. debug mode. currently i have three system. system1 is db machine. in this machine c drive is made it as ftp drive, system2 is web php system, syste,3 web php system. i am able to FTP file from system2 into system1(DB). but same command i am using in the system3 machine. but ftp not done, so i expecting details trace. so i am looking the debug command

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280014/how-to-get-the-ftp-error-when-using-php

Comment: Refered sample snippet just returning Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Opening ASCII mode data connection.. i would like to know the detailed trace.

Comment: if it's an exception, then use try/catch blocks, and examine the error message from the error object.

Answer (score 0):

run your php script in the terminal to get step by step script execution trace, use:

```
/usr/local/php/bin/php filename.php
```

=)